# Libaries like Ngx-toastr, bootstrap dont work to angular.json What can i do?

Tags: angular

I am working angular 11 and i am addin some css files. But when i add these extensions to angular.json it does not work.
Etc

```
 "styles": [
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css",
          "./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
          "./node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
```

However, Bootstrap and font-awesome work when I add it to index.htlm file like this.

```
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

```
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

but libaries lies toastr and toastr will still not work. What can i do ?
Please help me

Comment: Are you using the correct styles property in your angular.json? There are two possibilities. One is for test. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51998505/styles-not-picking-from-angular-json-styles-array-angular-6-but-working-fine-wi

Comment: i checked this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51998505/styles-not-picking-from-angular-json-styles-array-angular-6-but-working-fine-wi but overlooked the comment about the test. realy thank you for you ansver.